# get_terms() for custom taxonomy related to another taxonomy

Tags: terms, multi-taxonomy-query

I have this weird thing to do and I have no idea how to do it. Ok, so:

I have two custom taxonomies: `collections` and `categories` (both are prefixed, but for the sake of simplicity, I'll use these short names). A post will have a category and will be added into a collection.

What I have to do is to display all posts from a specific taxonomy - `categories` (already did this) and only show `collections` terms that have posts in the selected category. Some kind of `hide_empty` but based on another taxonomy. Make sense?

Since I use WPML plugin (that is known for adding stuff into sql query), I would like a solution that not involve the rewrite of the whole query.

So, any idea would be welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can try getting all the posts IDs from the first taxonomy

```
$objects = get_posts( array( 'category' => 'history', 'numberposts' => -1, ) );
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    $objects_ids[] = $object->ID;
}
```

Then get the terms from the second taxonomy associated with them:

```
$collections = wp_get_object_terms( $object_ids, 'collections' );
```

Comment: I did, no luck. I need to fetch terms, not posts.

I'll probably end by converting second taxonomy into hierarchies for the first tax.

Comment: Aaaah. So you need to display all posts from category `history` and show (maybe on the side) just collections from this category.

Comment: Yes. I decided to merge both taxonomies (as hierarchical terms), since I _haded_ no good reason to split them in two.

Comment: You can run into problems if you need the same collection under multiple categories. See the updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I did something that sounds familiar with your case and the easiest way to do it was using the [Posts 2 Posts](http://scribu.net/wordpress/posts-to-posts) plugin.

Comment: Can you give me more details on that? Maybe a quick example?